# How can update record in Sugar ORM?

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm new to Sugar ORM and want to update simple one record of the table

```
List<PagingSelected> finds = (List<PagingSelected>) PagingSelected.findWithQuery(PagingSelected.class,"Select * from "+NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("PagingSelected")+" LIMIT 1"); 
                finds.get(0).setNext(true);
                finds.get(0).update();
```

This does not update the table with the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sugar ORM your class PagingSelected is extention of SugarRecord, so you can use base methods.

```
List<PagingSelected> finds = (List<PagingSelected>) PagingSelected.findWithQuery(PagingSelected.class,"Select * from "+NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("PagingSelected")+" LIMIT 1"); 
finds.get(0).setNext(true);
PagingSelected.saveInTx(finds.get(0));
```

Comment: thanks for pay attention to me,please wait to test your code

Comment: You can use faster and more productive ORM - Room, DBFlow, GreenDao.
Why are u using sugar orm? You can check comparison: https://github.com/AlexeyZatsepin/Android-ORM-benchmark